# Laravel 5.3 and API authentication using api_token

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, laravel-5.3

I have followed the steps of this [tutorial](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51) in order to setup API authentication in Laravel 5.3 using the `auth:api` middleware.

Everything is working as expected apart from I am finding that in order to successfully access my API, I only need to provide an API token for *any* user in my `users` table rather than the token linked to the user currently logged in.

Is this expected behaviour because this middleware is stateless? I am using [AdLdap2](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel) to authenticate users but I can't see what I could be doing wrong especially as I have followed the steps in the tutorial above.

I have also had a look at [TokenGuard](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.html) which deals with API token validation but can't see any logic that ensures the token matches that of the user logged in.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the authentication works like expected. The only thing auth:api does is making sure you are authenticated to access the protected routes. If you want to protect a specific route to only one user you could use [Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#gates)

So if you have a route to access a user like below and you want the user that's logged in to only access herself you can add a gate.

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', function ($id) {
    $userYourTryingToView = User::find($id);

    if (Gate::allows('get-user', $userYourTryingToView)) {
        // The user is allowed to access herself, return the user.
        return response()->json($userYourTryingToView);
    }

    // User is not authenticated to view some other user.
    return response('Unauthenticated', 403);
});
```

And in your app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php

```
/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('get-user', function ($authenticatedUser, $userYourTryingToView) {
        return $authenticatedUser->id == $userYourTryingToView->user_id;
    });
}
```

Comment: My use case is centered on ensuring any API route is accessed with an API token that matches that of the currently authenticated user. Can you provide a Gate example which works for this?